# what is the better way to design web pages for different levels/privilege of user?

Tags: javascript, html

I am designing web pages for different levels/privileges of user.
so what is the better way to design?
and What is the safest way?

1)To design different pages for different levels/privileges of users?

Or

2)To design a page and disable several items for the lower level/privilege user?

Comment: Do you want to know which framework you should use to get things done easily.

Comment: I guess that depends on the complexity of the specific page. Either way, you should minimize code duplication.

Comment: I want to know is should i create different pages for different level/privileges of user of just in single page make visible or disable the content of the page as per the privileges?? And which is the safest way??

Answer (score 1):

You should use a templating engine for your pages, regardless of the language. This template should allow you to use conditional statements to include certain parts depending on the users level. Then, you can easily render the page (depending on the engine, and how it's installed of course) using something like this:

```
render('dashboard', {
    level: 'basic',
    username: 'johndoe',
});
```

This allows you to easily pass any variables. Most MVC frameworks have a built in render engine, or if you're using Node.js for example you could use something like EJS.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.but i want to know which is the safest way to design page, to give privilege like u mentioned above or to create pages for different levels of user?

Comment: That's your decision based on the site architecture. If you have two levels for example, user and admin, have a separate page for admins. However, if you have user, pro and admin, then you might want to create one page for all users and enable some stuff only for pro users, and have an admin page as before.

Comment: thanks that was a really helpful information for ma project.